# Differences in animation-timing-function between browsers? I just want linear

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to set up a css animation that will work in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera to animate the width of some coloured bars back and forth while retaining the overall width to fit the page.

I set up a demo at http://codepen.io/marblegravy/pen/rxhym

If you open it in Chrome, it works exactly as I want with it sticking to the edges of the page (whatever the width so it will work in a responsive layout).

In Firefox, Safari and Opera however, it appears that the `animation-timing-function: linear;` or the linear declaration in `animation: bulge4 7s infinite alternate-reverse linear;` isn't taking effect and the whole thing scales back and forth.

I am using [Prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/) to shortcut the coding on Codepen, but I don't think that's where the problem is.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You are animating the width trough CSS Tricks/Hacks. As CSS is interpreted different across browsers it will give different results. Also because this is a trick all browsers will interpret it on their own way.

You could make an simular setup trough jQuery Ui. For example animate can also scale sizes of elements, colors etc. In my opinion  this is an better and more solid alternative then using CSS Tricks.

More information can be found at http://jqueryui.com/docs/animate

Comment: I know it's possible to do with js and it certainly is the more robust way.. CSS animate is still in draft, but it's all valid - it's not a trick...

Comment: Please run your CSS then trought the W3C CSS validator found here : http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ and let me know...

Comment: If we all waited for css to be fully valid through the W3C we'd never innovate. Thanks for your suggestion - it's not the answer I'm looking for though. I'll keep digging.

Comment: You are right but as long it is not a standard, every browser maker can interpreted the style as how they judge, is the best way. There for if you want a more solid solution use existing styles and methods..